# How to convert a 5 digit INT to date

Tags: t-sql

I apologise if this question has been asked but I cannot find an answer that quite fits.

I have a database with dates stored as 5 digit integers.  I can covert these to datetime, however the dates are showing in the future.

For example,

```
select convert(datetime,StartDate,103)
from dpm.Schedule
where ScheduleID like 50003;
```

Gives the results of

2107-05-31 00:00:00:000 but this date should actually be 26/05/2008.

I am pretty new to T-SQL and have looked for sometime to find the answer to this but I am reaching the end of my sanity.

Comment: But what is the actual value stored in StartDate column? When using convert function on top of int data type, I think Sql Server will add the integer value to 1900-01-01 (you can try select convert(datetime, 0, 103)).

Comment: Assuming that the integer is a number of days, you can calculate back to the base date of the system since you know a pair of integer and corresponding date (50003 = 26 May 2008) and then work forward to convert any other integer value: `select DateAdd( dd, -50003, '20080526' ) as BaseDate, Cast( DateAdd( dd, 50003, '18710701' ) as Date ) as Something;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot answer because you are doing a lot of confusion. To start **5003** is the **Id** of the record and **[StartDate]** is the value you are trying to convert.
Also drop using operator **LIKE** in the Id

Example:

```
select convert(datetime,50003,103)
```

returns:

```
2036-11-26 00:00:00.000
```

but you are trying to convert the value returned by

```
select StartDate
from dpm.Schedule
where ScheduleID = 50003;
```

Please edit your question and show us a nice example using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6)

Comment: SQL Fiddle is really slow lately, though. Most often, it is impossible to work with.

Comment: Sometimes it gor slow, that's why in general I work local and just paste my examples to it =)